# Capturar petición cancelada en HttpInterceptor. Angular8

Tags: angular, http

Estoy teniendo un problema en una aplicación realizada con Angular 8.

Tengo un spinner a nivel de aplicación que se activa por cada petición http realizada y se desactiva en las respuestas.

Estas peticiones son capturadas por un HttpInterceptor que muestra un spinner de carga y cuando se obtiene la respuesta este se oculta. 
El problema viene cuando alguna de esas llamadas http se cancelan, como en este ejemplo:

```
 search(param: string) {
    return terms.debounceTime(SEARCH_DEBOUNCE)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap(term => this.search(param));
  }
```

El código de arriba pertenece a un buscador de texto en el que cuando se deja de escribir por un periodo de tiempo se realiza la búsqueda. Cuando se hace demasiado rápido, pueden llegar a realizarse varias peticiones simultáneas que switchMap se encarga de cancelar.
Por este motivo, cuando se cancelan las peticiones, el interceptor no es capaz de obtener el estado  de esa cancelación y por lo tanto el spinner nunca desaparece.

El interceptor hace algo como esto:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<any> {
    // se muestra el spinner

    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError(error => {
        // manejo del error y cierre de spinner
      }),
      finalize(() => {
        // entra para todas las respuestas excepto las peticiones canceladas, que no tienen respuesta.
      })
    );
```

Por lo tanto para esos casos en que la request es cancelada o abortada, no puedo detener el spinner.

Comment: Puedes hacer un ejemplo funcional en https://stackblitz.com/?